# pgfplots: coordinate dropped

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

Consider the following graph:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
       xmin=1.1,xmax=1.5,
       xlabel={$Q^2$},
       ylabel={$\alpha_{\textrm{eff}}\left(Q^2\right)$},
       axis on top,
       ticks=none,
       scaled ticks=false, 
       legend style={at={(0.5,1.)},anchor=north,legend cell align=left,legend plot pos=left, font=\small,draw=none,fill=none} ,
      ]
  \addplot[color=red,samples=300] {1/(1 - 2 * ln x)};
  \addlegendentry{$\alpha$}
  \addplot[color=blue,samples=300] {1/(2 * ln x)};
  \addlegendentry{$\alpha_s$}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The two functions used to not have any any discontinuity in the regime used for the plot - they should behave regularly. However, I get lots of these:

```
NOTE: coordinate (2Y1.6876381e-2],3Y0.0e0]) has been dropped because it is unbounded (in y). (see also unbounded coords=jump)
```

Can somebody explain me what is going on here and how I can avoid these messages? I'm not interested in merely suppressing them - I would like to understand what's the reason for them to appear in the first place.

Also I have noticed that changing the number of samples affects the plot in a surprising way:

`samples=300`

[image: with 300 sampling points]

`samples=200`

[image: with 200 sampling points]

`samples=100`

[image: with 100 sampling points]

`samples=50`

[image: with 50 sampling points]

I am suprised by the extreme jumps in the last graph - it looks like there are only 2-3 points used... what is the reason for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you did not explicitly specify a domain (independent of the axis limits), `pgfplots` is using its default domain of [-5,5]. So although there are no discontinuities in the area that you *see*, `pgfplots` is indeed trying to plot in the area near the discontinuity. Resolve this issue by specifying the key `domain=1.1:1.5`; this can be done for all plots in the `axis` options list or per-plot in the `\addplot` commands.

The sampling issue is related: the samples are distributed over the domain, not the area viewed in the axis viewport. So in the last example you have 50 samples total, but you only see 2 (per plot) in the viewable area of the axis.

Here you can see the `domain` specified to avoid the warnings. We can now see 10 samples across the domain as well (I specified `samples=10`).

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
       xmin=1.1,xmax=1.5,
       domain=1.1:1.5,
       samples=10,
       xlabel={$Q^2$},
       ylabel={$\alpha_{\textrm{eff}}\left(Q^2\right)$},
       axis on top,
       ticks=none,
       scaled ticks=false, 
       legend style={at={(0.5,1.)},anchor=north,legend cell align=left,legend plot pos=left, font=\small,draw=none,fill=none} ,
      ]
  \addplot[color=red] {1/(1 - 2 * ln x)};
  \addlegendentry{$\alpha$}
  \addplot[color=blue] {1/(2 * ln x)};
  \addlegendentry{$\alpha_s$}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]