# pgfplots: coordinate has been dropped because it is unbounded

Tags: pgfplots

After compiling the code I get: `coordinate (0Y0.0e0],4Y0.0e0]) has been dropped because it is unbounded (in y)`. [Here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/160991/pgfplots-coordinate-dropped) the solution was to specify a domain. I did it, hence I do not understand why I get this message.

```
\documentclass[border=0.5cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
 \pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis} [
        xmin=0,xmax=1,
        ymin=0,ymax=1,grid=major,
        xlabel={$F_{\textrm{Kleb}}$},ylabel={$y/\delta$}, ylabel style={rotate=-90},
        %width=6cm,height=4.5cm,
        domain=0:1,samples=50]
        \addplot [mark=none] {((1-x)/(5.5*x))^1/6};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You divide by zero (div/0). This is not a pgfplots problem. You have to restrict the domain to 0.001:1 for example. I'll prepare an answer to show you the effect,

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner: Alternatively you could keep the x domain as is and restrict the y domain to some finite maximum like `restrict y to domain=0:1000`. The downside is that you'll have to ensure that the value is large enough to ensure the line is connected to the plot border.

Comment: @Guho See my update.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## My Solution

For `x=0` the `y` value goes to `+inf` (positive infinity). This is normal for this kind of hyperbolic functions.  Therefore you should use a domain that starts at a value `>0` like `0.001`. You could easily test this in Excel for example (on my system the comma is the decimal separator).

[image]

See bounded and unbounded functions on Wikipedia ([Link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_function)).

> For x=0 the y value for your equation is infinity so you should use a domain that starts
>   with 0.001 (0.001:1) for example.

```
\documentclass[border=0.5cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
 \pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis} [
        xmin=0,xmax=0.01,
        ymin=0,ymax=100,grid=major,
        xlabel={$F_{\textrm{Kleb}}$},ylabel={$y/\delta$}, ylabel style={rotate=-90},
        %width=6cm,height=4.5cm,
        domain=0.0001:0.01,samples=1000]
        \addplot [mark=none] {((1-x)/(5.5*x))^1/6};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

## Alternative Solution by User [Guho](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/89497/guho) (Not Tested by Me)

> @Dr.ManuelKuehner: Alternatively you could keep the x domain as is and
>   restrict the y domain to some finite maximum like restrict y to
>   domain=0:1000. The downside is that you'll have to ensure that the
>   value is large enough to ensure the line is connected to the plot
>   border.